# How can I cache (cache on my server) a site like Stackoverflow written in PHP

Tags: php, caching

I have tried to make my own SO for practice and am basically finished the basics. I have never cached anything more then javascript and css before. I have tried searching SO and google but I cant get clear on the following questions.

I also want to know what pages should be cached on the server. i.e should I cache a page like questions/45/title-goes-here?

How do I cache the header part if the username is different for everyone?

Do I dump the whole file to a text file for every single question? That doesn't seem very practical.

How do i set up a cache page to be used by the back button.

Sorry if the answers are obvious, but I have researched and just dont get it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little clearer where you want to cache things exactly? Are you talking about server-side caching or HTTP caching? Why do you only want to cache the header?

Comment: @deceze I want to know what to cache, I thought every page should be cached but then I got stuck what to do about the username in the header page!

Comment: So you mean server-side caching of the generated HTML? It doesn't always make sense on highly dynamic pages such as SO.

Comment: @deceze then why when I press the back button does it read it from the cache?

Comment: That's the browser caching the page locally. You just do this by setting appropriate HTTP headers telling the browser to not bother reloading the page for x amount of time. I think SO has this set to one minute.

Comment: @deceze oh I see. Thanks will try that. Well anyway, how do people go about caching dynamic sites?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12270/discussion-between-yehuda-and-deceze)

Comment: @deceze do you mean that after a minute you will not be able to hit the back button on SO without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1):

Your caching system is basically a set of tools to do quick lookups on things that are "expensive" to generate and don't change much.

**To determine what should be cached, you need to study your work so far and figure out what parts are taking the most CPU or database time.  And then cache those.**

For caching StackOverflow, perhaps one strategy might be to generate a cache object for the HTML of each question, including s that could be populated afterwards using JavaScript.  The process of looking up the question and tags might be more time consuming than just looking up the single cache entry that includes both.

For your header, that's also a candidate for JavaScript, as long as you don't mind skipping graceful degradation of the user interface.  The cached username section of the header might look something like:

```
<div id="username"></div>
```

Then JavaScript, generated by something not cached, would "fill in the blanks" with personalized content.

Hope this helps.